# umask and chmod unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am trying to write simple program that changes file privileges using *umask* and *chmod* system-calls, but file privileges do not change as expected.

This is what I've tried:

- Set *umask* to 0;
- If the file doesn't exist, it is created by *open* system-call using O_CREAT flag, and then privileges are set to *mode* passed by command-line argument;
- If the file already exists, change its privileges by *chmod* system-call.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define check_error(expr, userMsg) \
    do { \
        if (!(expr)) { \
            perror(userMsg); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
        } \
    } while(0)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    check_error(3 == argc, "use: ./umask path mode");

    mode_t oldUmask = umask(0);
    long mode = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 8);

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, mode);
    if (-1 == fd) {
        if (EEXIST == errno) {
            printf("[file already exists]\n");
            check_error(-1 != chmod(argv[1], mode), "chmod failed");
        } else {
            perror("open failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        close(fd);
    }

    umask(oldUmask);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

After compiling i tried:

```
./umask 1.txt 0744
```

Expected privileges would be -rwxr--r--, but after

```
ls -l
```

I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 окт 19 14:06 1.txt
```

Again, after

```
./umask 1.txt 0744
```

this time I expected that *chmod* would internally change the privileges on existing file, but after listing I get the same:

```
[file already exists] 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 окт 19 14:06 1.txt
```

Both *umask* and *chmod* failed to set privileges as expected. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong, and I tried your code on my machine (MacOS, clang) and it worked fine.  So I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: It looks like you're running the program as root.  I wouldn't expect that to make any difference, but do you get the same behavior if running as an ordinary user?

Comment: For troubleshooting, considering running you code under strace (strace ./a.out ...). This will provide you with the input and result of each system call.

Comment: @SteveSummit
I've realized what's the problem: since I am using Linux on Virtual machine, I created the file from it in a shared-folder with a Windows host machine. Therefore I am not actually an owner of the file and the host doesn't let me change the privileges from the virtual Linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that I've created and tested the program on were created in a shared folder between Windows host machine and Linux virtual machine. I've started the program from Linux, trying to change the privileges of the file which I am not the owner of - it's Windows host machine, and that's why it doesn't let me change the privileges.